# Use of unasigned variable error, I cannot think of a workaround

Tags: c#

If you look by to the bottom of the my code, I use the variable 'value', when I do I get a 'use of unassigned variable' error. does anyone know any secret wizard tricks or a different layout for the code that would enable me to use the same variable in that if statement and use it in a separate while loop (different blocks)? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator V1.00");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");

            bool bool1 = false;
            double value;
            while (bool1 == false)
            {
                try
                {
                        value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        bool1 = true;
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
                    bool1 = false;
                }
            }
            bool bool2 = false;
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Now enter an operator such as '+' or '*' ");

            char op;
            double value2;
            while (bool2 == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    op = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                    bool2 = true;

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("Now input your second number");
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
                    value2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (op == Convert.ToChar("+"))
                    {
                        double result =  value + value2;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                    }

                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Now enter an operator such as '+' or '*' ");
                    bool2 = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better is `while( ! bool1)` and even better would be using a more descriptive name such as `done` or  `completed` or the like. Naming variables `bool1, bool2` is considered bad style.

Answer (score 1):

Give your variable a default value:

```
double value = 0;
```

It has no idea if you'll ever get into that `while` loop to set the `value` variable.

```
while (bool1 == false)
```

What if `bool1` were initialized to `true` in your code? The loop would never execute, and `value` wouldn't have  a value later on in the method.

Also, FWIW, you'll want to rename all those variables (value, value2, bool1, bool2, etc) to be more meaningful so you can quickly tell later on what they mean.

Comment: "*What if bool1 were initialized to true in your code?*" - actually that's not the case. `bool1` is initialized properly.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider  just an infinite loop like while(true). Just use break statements to break out when valid input is received.

That way you can do away with your bool1, bool2, bool3

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to suggest. The less code you need to write, the less opportunity for bugs to creep in.

Comment: "*The less code you need to write, the less opportunity for bugs*" - That's only half-way thruth. Given the tasks to fix a problem in a 10 liner full of unmaintainable, highly "optimized" constructs that some "genius" wrote who's long out of reach, or in a 50 liner that looks totally boring simple, I take the 50 liner and leave you with the "genius" code. Been there, done that.

Comment: @JensG I never suggested and never would suggest that code brevity is the only criterion for maintainability, but it is *a* criterion. I see no relevant difference for declaring this suggestion unmaintainable, but please do elaborate if you do.

Comment: "*I see no relevant difference for declaring this suggestion unmaintainable*" => "*I never suggested and never would suggest that*" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're only assigning value in a try block, which may not complete. If you assign a default value at declaration, it should work.

Also, consider using double.TryParse() inside a while(true) loop instead...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Put your input request in a separate method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator V1.00");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");

            double value = GetValue();

            bool bool2 = false;
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Now enter an operator such as '+' or '*' ");

            while (bool2 == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    char op = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                    bool2 = true;

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("Now input your second number");
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");

                    double value2 = GetValue();

                    if (op == Convert.ToChar("+"))
                    {
                        double result =  value + value2;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                    }

                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Now enter an operator such as '+' or '*' ");
                    bool2 = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private static double GetValue()
        {
            bool bool1 = false;

            while (bool1 == false)
            {
                try
                {
                        return Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
                    bool1 = false;
                }
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

As a side effect you can reuse the method for getting `value2` with the same error handling.

Answer (score 0):

By separating both kinds of input (double and char) into methods you get some benefits. Not only your actual problem will be solved, also the code is much clearer because we separated different levels of detail, or abstraction levels. Last not least we can throw out the `bool` variables entirely. I leave the boilerplate out for brevity:

```
static double EnterNumber(string descr)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(descr);
            var value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            return value;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            // just try again
        }
    }
}


static char EnterOperator(string descr)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(descr);
            var op = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            if( ("+-*/").IndexOf(op) >= 0)
                return op;

        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            // just try again
        }
    }
}

static void Calculate(double val1, char op, double val2)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            Console.WriteLine(val1 + val2);
            break;
        case '-':
            Console.WriteLine(val1 - val2);
            break;
        case '*':
            Console.WriteLine(val1 * val2);
            break;
        case '/':
            Console.WriteLine(val1 / val2);
            break;
        default: 
            Console.WriteLine("Unhandled operator "+op);
            break;
    }
}
```

That leaves us with a main routine with this content:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calculator V1.00");
    Console.WriteLine("----------------");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    double val1 = EnterNumber("Enter first number:");
    char op = EnterOperator("Now enter an operator such as '+' or '*':");
    double val2 = EnterNumber("Now input your second number:");

    Calculate(val1, op, val2);
}
```